# GWT: development mode behaves different from server mode

Tags: regex, deployment, gwt-mvp, gwt-hosted-mode

this is a 10 million dollar question! I am developing with GWT 2.1.1, MVP framework, GIN and deploying on tomcat 6.
Never had any problem so far.
I added a regular expression (RE) client side to check an input text input. Well, it happens that the RE works fine in development mode but doesn't when deploying on tomcat. I also tried to deploy on tomcat in development mode and the RE works fine. I only have problems when deploy the related war file on tomcat.

Here's the code:

```
private static String VALID_INPUT_STRING =  "((\\A[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,4}\\z)|(\\A[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\\.[0-9]\\z)|(\\A0\\.[1-9]\\z))";

    public boolean isValidInput(String input) {
        if(
                input.isEmpty() || input.matches(VALID_INPUT_STRING)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }    

   if (e.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER 
            && isValidInput(inputValue.getText())) {

                hideInsertPopUp();

    }
```

Any idea?? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
I used **String.matches** client side. Actually GWT uses com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp under the hood.

**com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp** does not support **\A** and **\z**, so I replaced those with **^** and **$**. That works fine for me now.